# How to use an existing PostGIS database in a Flask web app

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, geoalchemy2

I'm building a web app using Flask and a PostGIS database I already created.  I'm struggling to get Flask-SQLAlchemy to accept the geom column of my existing database.  I declare `db` in an **init**.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, request, current_app
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

import os, logging

db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
```

My code for my models.py file looks like this:

```
from app import login, db
from datetime import datetime
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry
from time import time
from flask import current_app

class Streets(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    street = db.Column(db.String(50))
    geom = db.GeometryColumn(db.LineString(2))
```

The error I get is: `AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'GeometryColumn'`

And if I try to remove `db.` from the geom line, I get this error: `NameError: name 'GeometryColumn' is not defined`

Because Flask-SQLAlchemy wants you to declare a column using `db.Column`, it seems to override geoalchemy2.  Has anyone found a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not override GeoAlchemy2. You could use `GeometryColumn` as a column, if you were using the [previous version of GeoAlchemy](http://geoalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html).

The first error is caused by the fact that the `SQLAlchemy` object from Flask-SQLAlchemy [gives you access to functions etc. from `sqlalchemy` and `sqlalchemy.orm`](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/quickstart/#road-to-enlightenment). It does not include stuff from GeoAlchemy2 or such.

The second error is due to not having the name `GeometryColumn` in scope. You do import `Geometry` from `geoalchemy2`, but don't use it.

Reading the [GeoAlchemy2 ORM tutorial](http://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/orm_tutorial.html) you'd notice that geometry columns are defined as

```
geom = Column(Geometry('POLYGON'))
```

or in your case

```
geom = db.Column(Geometry('LINESTRING'))  # dimension defaults to 2
```

Note that `db.Column` is `sqlalchemy.schema.Column`, just in another namespace.

Comment: Thanks!  Now I understand!  I also found after searching and searching, another post that used this syntax: `geom = db.Column(Geometry(geometry_type='LINESTRING'))` which did the trick.  I assume I could remove the "geometry_type" and it would still work as you suggested.

Comment: The link to the other post I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069595/flask-with-geoalchemy-sample-code